# Rails active record serialisation inside migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am doing a migration where I am moving data that is saved as a ruby Hash from one table to another. The column is saved as :text, and in the model the serialisation is defined as a Hash.

I want to move this column into another table but if I remove the line that specifies the serialisation type (which I want to do because the field will no longer exist), then the migration treats the data as a string. Is it possible to define how the data must be serialised in the migration file itself? so that future migrations from scratch don't break at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just define all needed info inside the migration file:

```
# db/migrate/20190219114703_move_data_to_another_table.rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  # here you need only the line that specifies the serialisation type
end

class MoveDataToAnotherTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    # here goes the migration itself
  end
end
```

Comment: oh cool, didn't realise you could do that, will verify that this works and give a green tick :)

Comment: @Makoto, happy to help you!